# XSLT 1.0 - exclude specific descending nodes based on conditions

Tags: select, xslt-1.0, multiple-conditions

Here is needed to match all nodes but NOT **( (** ***first*  TITLE**  among descendants **)** AND 
 **(*first* TITLE** who is **(** descendant of a GR.SEQ[@level=1]   AND  its inside text() DO NOT starts-with 'PART'**) ) )**

Many thanks in advance :-)

This is my current attempt: it catches the first descendant TITLE but not the second condition described.

```
    <xsl:template match="ANNEX|CONS.ANNEX">           

        . . .
    <!-- this variable select the needed node to be escluded but the some instruction doesn't work on the apply-templates statement -->
        <xsl:variable name="title_2" select="(.//GR.SEQ[@LEVEL=1]/TITLE[ not(starts-with(normalize-space(.), 'PART'))])[1]" /> 
          . . . 

    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[ not( 
                                    (  local-name() = 'TITLE' and  ancestor::GR.SEQ[@LEVEL=1]  and  not( starts-with(normalize-space (.) ,'PART'))     ) [1] 
                                             or 
                                        (local-name() = 'TITLE'  )[1]
                                )]" />  


  </xsl:template> 

    This is the XML source:

   <CONS.ANNEX>
     <TITLE>
      <TI>
        <P>ANNEX 5</P>
      </TI>
     </TITLE>
     <CONTENTS>
      <GR.SEQ LEVEL="1">
        <TITLE>
          <TI>
            <P>
              <HT TYPE="BOLD">QUALIFICATION OF PERSONNEL</HT>
            </P>
          </TI>
          <STI>
            <P>
              <HT TYPE="BOLD">[PART-XX]</HT>
            </P>
          </STI>
        </TITLE>
        <GR.SEQ LEVEL="2">
          <TITLE>
            <TI>
              <P>SUBPART GEN</P>
            </TI>
            <STI>
              <P>
                <HT TYPE="BOLD">
                  <HT TYPE="ITALIC">GENERAL REQUIREMENTS</HT>
                </HT>
              </P>
            </STI>
        </GR.SEQ>
        . . . 
        . . . 
     </GR.SEQ>  <!--  @LEVEL="1"  -->
    </CONTENTS>
  </CONS.ANNEX>
```

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
     <CONS.ANNEX>

      <CONTENTS>
       <GR.SEQ LEVEL="1">

        <GR.SEQ LEVEL="2">
          <TITLE>
            <TI>
              <P>SUBPART APT</P>
            </TI>
            <STI>
              <P>
                <HT TYPE="BOLD">
                  <HT TYPE="ITALIC">GENERAL REQUIREMENTS</HT>
                </HT>
              </P>
            </STI>
         </GR.SEQ>  <!--  @LEVEL="2"  -->
        . . . 
        . . . 
       </GR.SEQ>  <!--  @LEVEL="1"  -->
     </CONTENTS>
    </CONS.ANNEX>
```

Comment: I don't understand your conditions: (1)  *"first TITLE among descendants"* of what?; (2) an element is NEVER *"inside text"*.

Comment: Hi Michael thanks for reply! I mean (1) first TITLE descendant of CONS.ANNEX  - AND - (2) first TITLE descendant of GR.SEQ LEVEL="1" having [text()] that NOT starts with 'PART'. Hope this helps :-)